# Render unicodes in react using dangerously set innerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode

I have an api which returns string like this:

```
\n
<p>
  We\u00e2\u0080\u0099re looking for a Customer Success Manager, Scale to join
  our team of five \u00e2\u0080\u009cmisfits that fit\u00e2\u0080\u009d.&nbsp;
</p>
```

How can I render the unicodes properly in react?

Comment: In that example does the string contain actual unicode characters (in js that would be: "\u0080") or is it ascii where you have a backslash then u followed by hex digits (in js: "\\u0080") ?

Comment: This is the exact input which is coming from an api

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): (your text abbreviated) `'We\u00e2\u0080\u0099re looking for ... of five \u00e2\u0080\u009cmisfits that fit\u00e2\u0080\u009d.'.encode( 'iso-8859-1').decode( 'utf-8')` returns `'We’re looking for ... of five “misfits that fit”.'`. There are mangled characters `’` (U+2019 (`0xE2,0x80,0x99`), *Right Single Quotation Mark*), `“` (U+201C (`0xE2,0x80,0x9C`), *Left Double Quotation Mark*)
and `”` (U+201D (`0xE2,0x80,0x9D`), *Right Double Quotation Mark*)…

Answer (score -1):

"**decodeURIComponent**" function to decode the Unicode escape sequence

```
const data = '\\n <p>We\\u00e2\\u0080\\u0099re looking for a Customer Success Manager, Scale to join our team of five \\u00e2\\u0080\\u009cmisfits that fit\\u00e2\\u0080\\u009d.&nbsp;</p>';

const decodedNewString = decodeURIComponent(JSON.parse(`"${data}"`));
console.log(decodedNewString)

/*
I got this result I hope this code help you.
 <p>Weâre looking for a Customer Success Manager, Scale to join our team of five âmisfits that fitâ.&nbsp;</p>
*/
```

Comment: Why `decodeURIComponent` ?

Comment: in other words, if you remove `decodeURIComponent` from your snippet, what would it print? Why?